# Append one item to multiple lists Python

Tags: python, list, append

```
item_1 = foo

list_1 = []
list_2 = []
list_3 = []
```

Is it possible to append `item_1` to `list_1`, `list_2` and `list_3` in one line?

```
list_1.append(item_1)
list_2.append(item_1)
list_3.append(item_1)
```

seems very lousy to me; I have nearly 20 lists and I need one item in all of them.

Comment: You could put all of your lists into another list and then iterate over it and add your item.

Comment: Whenever you have variables like `x_1, x_2, ...` of similar type and purpose,  you should consider putting them in a list or other collection that allows dealing with them in bulk.

Comment: Having 20 lists, all managed independently, containing the same item feels lousy either way. Can you think of a better design?

Comment: `y = lambda x: (list_1.append(x), list_2.append(x), list_2.append(x))
y(item_1)`

Comment: perhaps there is a way of better designing, @DeepSpace, but I am a novice and at the moment, I don't see a better way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a list of lists and use a for loop to iterate over all of them.

```
item_1 = 'foo'

list_1 = []
list_2 = []
list_3 = []
```

Here we create a list of lists (it can be any length):

```
mylist = [list_1, list_2, list_3]
```

Next we iterate over all the lists in the main list, one by one.
Each list will be referenced by the target variable (in this case "l") and we can then call `.append()` on l.

```
for l in mylist:
    l.append(item_1)
```

To prove this works, we can then examine the main list and individual lists:

```
print(mylist)
[['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo']]

print(list_1)
['foo']

print(list_2)
['foo']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use loops:

```
lists_to_append_to = [list1,list2]
for list in lists_to_append_to:
     list.append(item_1)
```

if the names of the lists are really list_1,2 etc you should probably should a dictionary though:

```
lists = {
    1: list(),
    2: list()
}
```

In that case use the dictionary in the loop.

```
for current_list in lists:
     lists[current_list].append(item)
```

Comment: The dict loop is a little off as it iterates the keys. Also `list` is a terrible variable name as it shadows the built-in type.

Comment: @Johnfishmaster thank you for your tip, but my project is complicated enough at the moment and like I said before, I am a novice and not so familiar with dictionaries.

Comment: Thats an extra reason to use them. Trying new things is part of learning. However you should only use this if are used for similar purposes anyway.